# Cookies in <scrapy.Request> seems not working

Tags: cookies, scrapy, request

I am writing a `<Spider>`, and after login success in `<parse_login>`, I try to send a `<FormRequest>` by the response from `<parse_login>`. 
I got cookies from response of `<parse_login>`, and tried to add the cookies into `<FormRequest>`, but it failed, which causes a redirection to login page.

```py
# here is the method after `parse_login()`
# form data
def query_form(self, response: scrapy.http.Response):
    url = 'http://dev.soeasysdk.com/productProfit/issueCount2.do'
    cookies = {
        'name': 'joe@stackoverflow.com',
        'JSESSIONID': '...',
    }
    return [FormRequest(
        url=url,  
        cookies=cookies,
        meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']},
        method='POST',
        headers=self.headers,
        formdata={
            'app_name': '',
            'begin_date': str(self.start_date),
            'end_date': str(self.start_date),
        },
        callback=self.parse_page,
        dont_filter=True
    )]
```

```sh
# and here is the console log
DEBUG [19-10-21 14:47:54] scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect _redirect :43 Redirecting (302) to <GET *************> from <POST *************>
# redirect from expected url to login page, as I think and test in post man and shell, this happened when giving wrong cookies or without cookies
```

---

But when I try it in `<requests.request()>` and `curl` in shell with cookies, I can get the direct page content instead of login page.

```py
url = 'http://dev.soeasysdk.com/productProfit/issueCount2.do'
cookies = {
    'name': 'joe@stackoverflow.com',
    'JSESSIONID': '...',
}
res = requests.request(method='POST', cookies=cookies, url=url)
print(res.cookies)
print(res.content)
print(res.text)
```

```sh
curl -v --cookie "name=joe@stackoverflow.com; JSESSIONID=..." http://dev.soeasysdk.com/productProfit/issueCount2.do
```

The url link to a form query, accessing allowed with logged in.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried manually building a `Request` with the same data as your requests and curl tests? (no cookiejar, no `FormRequest` but just `method='POST'`, etc.? Could you show us your requests and Scrapy equivalents one after another, to see how they may be different?

Comment: @Gallaecio Hi! Thank you for your advice, I have edited my post, and form data had no effect to the request result.

Comment: The equivalent to `requests.request(method='POST', cookies=cookies, url=url)` is `Request(url, method='POST', cookies=cookies)`. That should work the same as your `requests.request` example. Does it?

Comment: @Gallaecio Yes, I have tried that, adding `cookies=cookies` in both `scrapy.Request` and `scrapy.FormRequest` but none of them worked. I also tried to change `setting.py` and failed too.

Comment: Did you also remove `meta`, `formdata` and `headers` from that test?

Comment: @Gallaecio oh... I did not. Thanks a lot! I will test it more comprehensively